# Need 2 decimals on operations

Tags: php

I have this php code and i want this operations to apear with 2 decimals only.
After the php code i'll put an example of what i receive on the output.

```
$Unir_Destino=$_POST['destino']; 
$tons=$_POST['tons'];
$descom=$_POST['descom'];
$remis=$_POST['remis'];
$fact=$_POST['fact'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("Destinos") or die (mysql_error()); 
$Precio= mysql_query("SELECT Precio FROM Destinos WHERE Destino ='$Unir_Destino'");
$Precio1 = mysql_fetch_array($Precio);
$Precio2 = ($Precio1['Precio']);
$Total = $Precio2 * $tons;
$iva = ($Total / 100) * 16;
$totiva = $Total + $iva;
$rete = ($Total / 100) * 4;
$toret = $totiva - $rete;


        <span style="font-family: Tahoma;">
            <b>Subtotal:</b>       <?php print "$$Total <br />";?>
            <b>IVA:</b>            <?php print "$$iva <br />"; ?>
            <b>Subtotal + IVA:</b> <?php print "$$totiva <br />";?>
            <b>Retencion:</b>      <?php print "$$rete <br />";?>
            <b>Total:</b>          <?php print "$$toret <br />";?>
        </span>
```

Subtotal: $6297.9 
IVA: $1007.664 
Subtotal + IVA: $7305.564 
Retencion: $251.916 
Total: $7053.648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's `number_format()` method

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Here's an example taken from the reference:

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

Comment: plus, although it wouldn't hurt to give an example along side that link

Comment: i used >> number_format($number, 2, ',', ' '); like this> $Total = number_format($Precio2 * $tons, 2, ',', ' '); but the other result of the operations that need $Precio2 gives me: Subtotal: $6 297,90 
IVA: $0.96 
Subtotal + IVA: $6.96 
Retencion: $0.24 
Total: $6.72

Comment: Based on your format, you can use the "without thousands separator" example. @pixanim